# How to read an IOS App project

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been learning Objective-C and IOS 5 development for about two month, and find some open source IOS App projects, now I try to read those source code, but when I begin, I don't know how to begin reading, can anybody give me some suggestions to make me to know how to read effectively. Thanks all.

Comment: You can start in the appdelegate and see which view controller is added to the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the AppDelegate and the RootViewController (Check the rootviewController by launching the application and noticing what loads up first). If you can't find a RootViewController of the project, add a simple line like:

```
 NSLog(@"I am in View 1");
```

in each of the class and see which gets called first. Then, after you've found your first controller, follow the code from there to see what's invoked and in response to what.

I recommend starting with a simple open source project rather than reading something complex like a Cocos 2D game. For example, start with example codes that Apple provides in developer documentation - using multiple view controllers, table view code, etc.

**EDIT**: Simple Solution - Follow the Storyboard if its used in the open source project you're looking at. Else, refer above.

Comment: Thanks, begin with simple one.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking at the layout of the `Storyboard` (in iOS 5, this is becoming the normal and preferred way of designing the UI for most people).  Look at the initial scene and then use the identity inspector to see what the subclassed `ViewController` is.  Look through that VC's code and see what is going on.  Run the app to see how the executed flow compares to the `Storyboard` design.